making a post or a get request in a nested jsonserver array
Current Setup:

I have a JSON Server running with a db.json file that includes a products array. Each product has an id and a reviews array.

Example db.json


"products": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
            "image":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/17/14/27/headphones-3683983_1280.jpg",
            "description": "High-quality wireless Bluetooth headphones with noise cancellation and long battery life.",
            "price": 89.99,
            "category": "Electronics",
            "stock": 150,
            "rating": 4.5,
            "specifications": {
              "batteryLife": "20 hours",
              "weight": "250 grams",
              "connectivity": "Bluetooth 5.0",
              "color": "Black"
            },
            "reviews": [
                {
                  "reviewId": "r1",
                  "userId": "u001",
                  "reviewerName": "Alice Johnson",
                  "rating": 5,
                  "comment": "Excellent headphones! The sound quality is amazing and the noise cancellation is top-notch.",
                  "date": "2024-08-15"
                },
                {
                  "reviewId": "r2",
                  "userId": "u002",
                  "reviewerName": "Bob Smith",
                  "rating": 4,
                  "comment": "Good value for the price. Comfortable to wear, but the battery life could be better.",
                  "date": "2024-08-16"
                },
                {
                  "reviewId": "r3",
                  "userId": "u003",
                  "reviewerName": "Charlie Davis",
                  "rating": 3,
                  "comment": "Average headphones. The sound is decent, but they feel a bit bulky.",
                  "date": "2024-08-17"
                }
              ]

          },



Problem:

I want to make a POST request to add a new review to the reviews array of a specific product. However, JSON Server does not support directly updating nested arrays like reviews out-of-the-box.

Specific Questions:

How can I set up a custom endpoint with JSON Server to handle adding a new review to the reviews array of a product?

What would a sample server.js setup look like for this use case?

How should I structure the POST request from the client side to ensure it updates the reviews array correctly?

Any guidance or examples on setting up custom endpoints with JSON Server and handling nested updates would be greatly appreciated!






